# Как задать другую схему в базе postgresql при миграции foreign key в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Только начинаю изучать Laravel. Столкнулась со следующей проблемой:база данных у меня в Postgresql,первая таблица(bbs) в схеме bbs, вторая таблица (users) в схеме systems. Необходимо создать внешний ключ (user_id) в таблице bbs.bbs на таблицу systems.users. Делаю так, как показано ниже. При попытке миграции artisan естественно ругается, что не может найти таблицу users. Как в миграции таблицы bbs правильно указать то, что таблица users в другой схеме postgresql? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('bbs.bbs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title',50);
        $table->text('content');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index('created_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('bbs.bbs');
    }
};
```

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('systems.users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

Comment: Никак, создавайте все таблицы в одной базе

Comment: Таблицы и так в одной базе, просто в разных схемах данных базы postgresql.

Comment: Нашла такое решение: вместо $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');  написала $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
     $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('systems.users')->onDelete('cascade');
   Ругается, но внешний ключ в базе данных создает.

Comment: Объясните, зачем вам эти схемы нужны? Если используете по принципу - так можно и поэтому использую то не надо так.

Comment: База данных очень большая, в ней много таблиц, разные уровни доступа. Мне в web-проекте нужно получить доступ только к небольшому количеству таблиц этой базы

Comment: Вы же сами их создаёте... А теперь уже откуда-то взялись много таблиц, к некоторым доступ нужен...